# Python How to find arrays that has a certain element efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given lists(a list can have an element that is in another list) and a string, I want to find all names of lists that contains a given string.

Simply, I could just go through all lists using if statements, but I feel that there is more efficient way to do so.

Any suggestion and advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Example of Simple Method** I came up with

```
arrayA = ['1','2','3','4','5']
arrayB = ['3','4','5']
arrayC = ['1','3','5']
arrayD = ['7']

foundArrays = []

if givenString in arrayA:
    foundArrays.append('arrayA')
if givenString in arrayB:
    foundArrays.append('arrayB')
if givenString in arrayC:
    foundArrays.append('arrayC')
if givenString in arrayD:
    foundArrays.append('arrayD')

return foundArrays
```

Comment: There are no strings or arrays in your sample code. I see ints and lists, though...

Comment: There's not much else you can do but checking all elements until you find the target. However you can use a for loop rather than repeating if blocks manually

Comment: perhaps a `for`-loop may shorted it: `for array in [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC, arrayD]:
    if givenString in array:
        foundArrays.append(array)`

Comment: @AdamSmith sorry for unclear example and explanation. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup in a list is not very efficient; a set is much better.

Let's define your data like

```
data = {    # a dict of sets
    "a": {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    "b": {3, 4, 5},
    "c": {1, 3, 5},
    "d": {7}
}
```

then we can search like

```
search_for = 3   # for example
in_which = {label for label,values in data.items() if search_for in values}
# -> in_which = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

If you are going to repeat this often, it may be worth pre-processing your data like

```
from collections import defaultdict

lookup = defaultdict(set)
for label,values in data.items():
    for v in values:
        lookup[v].add(label)
```

Now you can simply

```
in_which = lookup[search_for]    # ->  {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Comment: @Bothwell In second block of codes, should items be values instead?

Answer (score 0):

The simple one-liner is:

```
result = [lst for lst in [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC, arrayD] if givenString in lst]
```

or if you prefer a more functional style:

```
result = filter(lambda lst: givenString in lst, [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC, arrayD])
```

Note that neither of these gives you the NAME of the list. You shouldn't ever need to know that, though.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the latter more functional than the former.

Comment: Doesn't he want the name of the array and not the array itself? Of course, trying to do this is a very bad idea anyways. But perhaps add some guidance for the OP?

Comment: @ChristianDean if he wants the name of the array, he can't do it any more easily than his code. More pointedly: he shouldn't ever WANT the name of the array, and if he does he should try a different approach.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes I know that. I updated my original comment to reflect my stance on the matter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `filter`, `map`, and `reduce` are considered more of a functional approach than the usual imperative list comprehensions and for loops.

Comment: Note: In Python 3, if the OP also wants a list using your second method, they need to cast the  `filter` object to one explicitly:  `list(result)`. Also note that if you directly cast the `filter` object to a list in your second method, the first one - the list comprehension - is actually faster.

Comment: @AdamSmith I want the names of the arrays. What kind of approach can I do in that case then?

Comment: @AdamSmith list-comprehensions are *not imperative constructs*. Python borrows them from Haskell. They are purely functional.

Comment: @smchae write your code in some way that it doesn't need the name of the arrays. There should never be meaning in your variable names.

Comment: @smchae that's both pithy advice from the grizzled veteran, and practical advice. There is no (good, reliable) way to derive a variable name from its value. What's more there's nothing tying name to value. They're just name tags attached to the value. Ephemeral at best. If you need to attach a name to a value, use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Array names?

Try something like this with `eval()` nonetheless using `eval()` is evil

```
arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5,'x']
arrayB = [3,4,5]
arrayC = [1,3,5]
arrayD = [7,'x']

foundArrays = []
array_names = ['arrayA', 'arrayB', 'arrayC', 'arrayD']

givenString = 'x'

result = [arr for arr in array_names if givenString in eval(arr)]
print result

['arrayA', 'arrayD']
```

Comment: If you know `eval()` is evil then why posting this answer which adds nothing to the previous one but evilness?

Comment: Because we are all adults.